# how to change input type=date calender language/Localization?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change my calendar dates language English to french.

```
<input type="date" name="licence_date" id="licence_date" class="form-control">
```

[image]

I want to change this calendar language English to french

Comment: According to mozillas dev page (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) there is no such tag. Since there is no tag I don't think that there is any solution using the `input` element to especially localize your input. But in general browsers use their selected language (most the time its also the system language)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can assign a language to the input date type by changing the language of the page or the item itself, as documented on MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Localization

```html
<label for="licence_date">Licence Date</label>
<input type="date" name="licence_date" id="licence_date" lang="fr-CA">
```

However, that will not change the display language of the calendar shown, because that calendar element is a **browser UI** element, and the overwhelming majority of browsers only natively display one language at a time. Even Firefox, which supports multiple language packs, only uses the primary one chosen at any one time, and it's that UI language which it will show the input date picker with.

The good news is that your users will already see the date picker in their browser's language, no matter how obscure the language.

Comment: The code snippet is displaying the information in english and not in french (at least for me)

Comment: @Mbotet And your browser's UI language is French? Which browser are you using?

Comment: im actually using spanish from firefox DE, but tried on chrome and same. I think it only formats the numbers according to such country default. 
I was initially looking for translation when you open calendar and the name of the month to be translated. I ended up using jquery ui (datepicker widget) + theme (smoothness)
If you want more details i can provide ;)

Comment: Can we dictate this lang setting REGARDLESS of user's browser language preference ? If not, how do I achieve such functionality ?

Comment: @emre-ozgun You can't change the browser's UI. So if you want to do a different calendar picker, you need to build one in HTML/CSS or use an existing front-end component calendar picker...  There should be many around, including some with configurable languages

Comment: @frandroid, Windows allows the user to override locale formatting ("Region and Language" dialog). I've been using this since Win3.1 to have an English UI (because I want to dammit) and change the nonsensical (to me at least) MM/dd/yyyy format to dd-MM-yyyy. By ignoring this, Firefox is the only thing on my PC that displays US-style dates on these controls. So, technically, my browser is *not* using my language preferences.

Comment: @efotinis Indeed. But my answer is about calendar display in a webpage as per the browser, not about calendar display as per the operating system. If you want Firefox to use your system localization (which would then bubble up to the webpage display), there's an option for that:
https://superuser.com/a/1804828/292114