# Datatables filter by date bug

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, datatable

I have a table made with datatables with several filters and it works fine. The problem is that I have added a filter to filter by date range and, although the date selector is shown, it is marked and everything does not filter by the dates that I mark. Do you know where the problem is? By the way, the date I am working with is in DD MM YYYY format (Although if I have not made a mistake, the selector is the same).

I would also like to know if it is possible to translate the date picker into Spanish (the rest of the datatable is translated as seen in the code)

Thanks

```
var minDate, maxDate;
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
   function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
       var min = minDate.val();
       var max = maxDate.val();
       var date = new Date( data[0] );

       if (
           ( min === null && max === null ) ||
           ( min === null && date <= max ) ||
           ( min <= date   && max === null ) ||
           ( min <= date   && date <= max )
       ) {
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }
);
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Create date inputs
  minDate = new DateTime($('#min'), {
      format: 'Do MMMM YYYY'
  });
  maxDate = new DateTime($('#max'), {
      format: 'Do MMMM YYYY'
  });

    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#html5-extension thead tr')
        .clone(true)
        .addClass('filters')
        .appendTo('#html5-extension thead');

    var table = $('#html5-extension').DataTable({

        orderCellsTop: true,
        fixedHeader: true,


        footerCallback: function (row, data, start, end, display) {
        var api = this.api();

        // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
        var intVal = function (i) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ? i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 : typeof i === 'number' ? i : 0;
        };

        // Total over all pages
        total = api
            .column(7)
            .data()
            .reduce(function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0);

        // Total over this page
        pageTotal = api
            .column(7, { page: 'current' })
            .data()
            .reduce(function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0);

        // Update footer
        $(api.column(8).footer()).html('<th colspan="8" style="text-align:center"><h4>' + pageTotal.toFixed(2) + ' € / ' + total.toFixed(2) + ' €)</h4></th>');
    },

    "dom": 'B<"float-left"i><"float-right"f>t<"float-left"l><"float-right"p><"clearfix">',
    //"dom": 'Bfrtip<"lrtip"l>',
    "language": {
        "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/Spanish.json"
    },
        initComplete: function () {
            var api = this.api();

            // For each column
            api
                .columns()
                .eq(0)
                .each(function (colIdx) {
                    // Set the header cell to contain the input element
                    var cell = $('.filters th').eq(
                        $(api.column(colIdx).header()).index()
                    );
                    var title = $(cell).text();
                    $(cell).html('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" size="8"/>');

                    // On every keypress in this input
                    $(
                        'input',
                        $('.filters th').eq($(api.column(colIdx).header()).index())
                    )
                        .off('keyup change')
                        .on('change', function (e) {
                            // Get the search value
                            $(this).attr('title', $(this).val());
                            var regexr = '({search})'; //$(this).parents('th').find('select').val();

                            var cursorPosition = this.selectionStart;
                            // Search the column for that value
                            api
                                .column(colIdx)
                                .search(
                                    this.value != ''
                                        ? regexr.replace('{search}', '(((' + this.value + ')))')
                                        : '',
                                    this.value != '',
                                    this.value == ''
                                )
                                .draw();
                        })
                        .on('keyup', function (e) {
                            e.stopPropagation();

                            $(this).trigger('change');
                            $(this)
                                .focus()[0]
                                .setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
                        });
                });
        },
        "ordering": false,
        "responsive": true,
       buttons: [
          {
            extend: 'copyHtml5',
            footer: true,
            text: 'Copiar',
            exportOptions: {
               columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
           },
            text: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i><span> Copiar</span>'
          },
          {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            footer: true,
            autoFilter: true,
            sheetName: 'Facturas emitidas',
            exportOptions: {
               columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
           },
            text: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></i><span> Generar Excel</span>',
            filename: 'Listado de facturas emitidas',
          },
          {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            footer: true,
            exportOptions: {
               columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
           },
            text: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save-file"></i><span> Generar PDF</span>',
            filename: 'Listado de facturas emitidas',
          },
          {
            extend: 'print',
            footer: true,
            exportOptions: {
               columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
           },
            text: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i><span> Imprimir</span>',
          }
      ],
      "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "Todos"]]
    });
    $('#min, #max').on('change', function () {
         table.draw();
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: "_translate the date picker into Spanish_" - I think that depends on the browser/system language (not controllable at the HTML tag level). Does the following help? [how to change input type=date calender language/Localization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61186908/12567365). If not, maybe you can ask that as a separate question, where you can give full details.